# Too many tables to show in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

```
( 1 .. 250 / 451 )
```

I have 451 tables, but phpmyadmin by default only shows 250 tables,

how can I make it show the rest tables?

Comment: What on earth could use 451 tables? God... imagine that ER model!

Comment: You will have to stack a couple of phpMyAdmins together to show all of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try setting [`$cfg['MaxTableList']`](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#MaxTableList) to 451 (or 500) in your [`config.inc.php`](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/config.inc.php). requires phpMyAdmin 2.11.0 or greater.